# How can I embed a python file or code in HTML?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am working on an assignment and am stuck with the following problem:

I have to connect to an oracle database in Python to get information about a table, and display this information for each row in an .html-file. Hence, I have created a python file with doctype HTML and many many "print" statements, but am unable to embed this to my main html file. In the next step, I have created a jinja2 template, however this passes the html template data (incl. "{{ to be printed }}") to python and not the other way round. I want to have the code, which is executed in python, to be implemented on my main .html file.

I can't display my code here since it is an active assignment. I am just interested in general opinions on how to pass my statements from python (or the python file) into an html file. I can't find any information about this, only how to escape html with jinja.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: If I need to talk to a Python application, I setup a Flask server and use Javascript to send and receive information. I've never heard of anything that can run Python in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find information because that won't work. Browser cannot run python, meaning that they won't be able to run your code if you embed it into an html file. The setup that you need is a backend server that is running python (flask is a good framework for that) that will do some processing depending on the request that is being sent to it. It will then send some data to a template processor (jinja in this case work well with flask). This will in turn put the data right into the html page you want to generate. Then this html page will be returned to the client making the request, which is something the browser will understand and will show to the user. If you want to do some computation dynamically on the browser you will need to use **javascript** instead which is something a browser can run (since its in a sandbox mode).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Given name of calling program, a url and a string to wrap, output string in html body with basic metadata.

```
 def wrapStringInHTML(program, url, body):
    import datetime
    from webbrowser import open_new_tab

    now = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

    filename = program + '.html'
    f = open(filename,'w')

    wrapper = """<html>
    <head>
    <title>%s output - %s</title>
    </head>
    <body><p>URL: <a href=\"%s\">%s</a></p><p>%s</p></body>
    </html>"""

    whole = wrapper % (program, now, url, url, body)
    f.write(whole)
    f.close()

    open_new_tab(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. What I have right now is a perfectly working python file containing jinja2 and the html output I want, but as a python file. When executing the corresponding html template, the curly expressions {{name}} are displayed like this, and not as the functions executed within the python file. Hence, I still have to somehow tell my main html file to execute this python script on my webpage, which I cannot manage so far.

Unfortunately, it seems that we are not allowed to use flask, only jinja and django.